# global variable and ajax request - Why is my global variable not inscreased as i'm using async:false mode?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

With this wonderful website, i could learn how to set ajax requests in wordpress, but failed to use global variables. I'm still new in wordpress and ajax programming. 
My problem is as follows: I made a query to store 100 wp_posts in a global $stmts['getCriteriasposts'] array, and displayed the 4 first items in a grid. $wpdb_position is a global variable giving the current position in this stmts array. When a user clicks an item in the grid, i want to replace the current post by the next item to be read in the array, at the same position in the grid.
As four items have been displayed, before clicking any post, $wpdb_position = 4. 
But when i send the Ajax Request to increase the global variable $wpdb_position = 0, even though the ajax request is in synchronous mode, and the request works for local data. I don't see where i'm wrong.
Any help will be really useful.
Thanks a lot.

THe json output is 
Object
position: "2"
wpdb_position: 1

Below the code:

```
// Functions.php

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ajax_script_enqueuer' );

function ajax_script_enqueuer() {

    $nonce = wp_create_nonce("my_action_callback");
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/../../../js/epointplus/epointplusevalframe.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',            array(         'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')       )   );

}


add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_my_action', 'manage_callback_loadnext' );
add_action( 'admin_post_my_action', 'manage_callback_loadnext' );

function my_action_callback() {
global $wpdb;
global $stmts;
global $wpdb_position;

$wpdb_position  = $wpdb_position + 1;
//$criteria = $stmts['getCriteriasposts'][$wpdb_position];

$result['wpdb_position'] = $wpdb_position;
$result['position'] = $_POST["position"];

echo json_encode($result);
die();  // may not work, in this case, use start_session() and $_SESSION to access the cache
}


// in the '/../../../js/epointplus/epointplusevalframe.js
$(document).ready( function() {

   $(".EvalFrame").click( function() {

    $.ajax({
     type : "post",
     dataType : "json",
     async: false, // Mode : synchrone
     url : ajax_object.ajax_url,
     data : {
        action: 'my_action',
        nonce : jQuery(this).attr("data-nonce")
        },
    }) 
        .fail(function() {
            console.log('something went wrong');
            //$('#EvalFrame_'+ position).empty();
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            //$('#EvalFrame_'+position).html(data);
        });
```

Once again, the help of this website has proven really efficient.  I saw the use of global $wpdb often in examples that i thought global variables could be used. I was wrong. Using Patrick's comment, I modified the code. Now it works good! Thanks so much, i was stuck for a while on this!!!

```
function my_action_callback() {

// toujours le meme souci, les variables globales ne fonctionnent pas.
global $wpdb;

if (!session_id()) {session_start();}
//global $wpdb_position;

if (count($_SESSION['criteriasCache']) > 0 )    
{
    $newCriteria = array_pop($_SESSION['criteriasCache']);
}

//$stmts['getCriteriasposts'][$wpdb_position];

$result['ccount'] = count($_SESSION['criteriasCache']);
$result['criteria'] = displayfromunderlyingsupport($newCriteria,$_POST["position"]);
$result['position'] = $_POST["position"];
//$result['type'] = "success";

//echo displayfromunderlyingsupport($newCriteria,$position);

echo json_encode($result);
die();  // may not work, in this case, use start_session() and $_SESSION to access the cache
```

}

Comment: i dont see you using any global javascript variable...., if you are meaning one of the php globals, they dont persist between page calls, do as your one comment mentions _"use start_session() and $_SESSION to access the cache"_ though start_session should already be called by the wp framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot patrick. I was wondering about the scope of global variables in Ajax, but as i though global wpdb often in examples, i assumed PHP global form the template page were also available in the Ajax callback function.